# Encrypt and decrypt an IP

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to make an admin page in php and I want that admins can't see the real IP, only encrypted. I'm trying to do this because users say that if admins can see their real IP is not ok and can do bad things with it.
I want to encrypt only a part or two from ip, for example 127.0.x.1 or 127.x.1 and that x to be something encrypted. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is totally possible.

Comment: Do admins have access to the database? If not, just replace random letters with x's when you make the request to get a user's data.

Comment: No, admins can not access the database. Yeah I can replace with random letters but that letters must be linked to that IP because I use that random letters to see user logs, like /profile/iplog/127.x.1

Comment: You can come up with your own en/decryption - from something simple as replacing each number with a letter to something more advanced that uses a math algorithm.

Comment: Why not just hide the IP altogether from the admins and just store it as the regular value? or run some hash/encrypt function on the output..

Comment: @AndreiG. Are you really talking about the handling of IPs in PHP (please show your code) or are you talking about the IPs in the server log (Apache, nginx, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using crc32 and sha512 hash.

I'm using this function to show the IP to admins:

```
public static function readable_encrypted_ip($ip)
{
    $s = explode('.', $ip);

    $encrypt = hash('crc32', $s[1] . $s[2]);

    $result = $s[0] . "." . $encrypt . "." . $s[3];

    return $result;
}
```

And this function for using in links:

```
public static function encrypt_ip($ip)
{
    return hash('sha512', $ip);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?  
  $ip = "192.168.11.22";

  $parts = explode(".", $ip);

  $secret1 = 123;
  $secret2 = 321;

  $parts[2] = $parts[2] * $secret1;
  $parts[3] = $parts[3] * $secret2;

  $encrypted = implode(".", $parts);
?>
```

RESULT: 192.168.1353.7062

On the call to `/profile/iplog/192.168.1353.2706` just do reverse calculation.

Sure, algorithm can be more complex than just multiply to 'secret numbers'.

**SPECIAL NOTE: this is just an example! In real code instead of trivial `$parts[2] * $secret1` should be used symmetric crypto algorithm!**

Comment: That is not encryption, there is no key.

Comment: @zaph, this is simplest case of encryption using keys $secret1 and $secret2 :-)

Comment: Man, do you understand word 'example'?

Comment: I hope you are happy now

Comment: Where the keys are in the PHP source code? Also there is no real security provided. Don't try to invent your own crypto: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. Here is a chosen plain text attack: chosen: 1.1.1.1, encrypted: 1.1. **123**. **321** — oops there are the "keys". (updated for the updated answer)